# How are these answers answering the question?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, flagging, specific-question

I am talking about the question: [Does the Aitareya Brahmana ask sudras to serve the other three castes?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/43558/4732)

It is quite specific and clear. It asks whether the Aitreya Brahmana really asks the Sudras to serve the other three castes or not?

Although the asker provides a screenshot of a book he obviously is looking for a confirmation (or refutation) from another source.

Hence answerers should simply say YES or NO. If YES just post the exact location (verse numbers). There should end the answers.

None of the answers are actually doing that.

[This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43600/4732) says what various other scriptures say about the topic and then finally concludes that the verses of Aitreya Brahmana (if those are actually present in it and which is the real question here) must be rejected. How is this a valid answer for the question?

The [second answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43614/4732) too does not say anything about whether those verses actually exist in the said scripture or not but simply starts discussing "what Aitreya Upanishad actually means". So, how does this answer the question either?
I have flagged both the answers using custom reasons asking moderators to take action against them but no actions so far. My flags are pending since Nov 28 and hence I am forced to post here.

**UPDATE:**

My flag for [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43600/4732) has been declined.

> This is not an answer. One should simply say yes the said scripture
> says that and quote the relevant portion or say no. But here info is
> instead given about what other scriptures say about the topic. Must be
> deleted. – Rickross Nov 28 '20 at 6:14   declined - a moderator
> reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

So, can Mods please explain how is the said answer answering the question and why it must not be deleted?

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!!!! Honestly speaking I’ve been frustrated with the guy, didn’t know where to raise a voice. I’ve told him 2-3 times already and he refuses to accept his mistakes. He keeps arguing about wrong things. I’ve flagged many of his questions (1-3 were acted upon, some were declined due to wrong flag (NAA) and others are pending). You can have a look at the discussion [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43768/20129). Also he doesn’t cite any sources in any answers. Except for his Upanishad translation answer and the one about Deep sleep maya recently all are x

Comment: Could there be an agenda? The community is welcome to everyone irrespective of where they come from, but when a user constantly goes against site policy and hardly any answers are taken care off, it may signal at something grave, is it? Now I’ve used the custom flag

Comment: This is a site about learning about Hinduism. So everyone is allowed to participate here as long as they stick to that. Problem arises when there is some hidden agenda of maligning the religion or something else. We can not ofcourse know for sure whether there are some hidden agendas unless they become open through the actions of the users and then we can resort to flagging etc. to tackle them @Archit

Comment: yes exactly, precisely! I also feel he recently downvoted the Shudra sanskara question and answer randomly. It’s an awesome well compiled answer. There was no reason for that. The issue is due to busy/insufficient moderators his flags also aren’t sorted. There was one very offensive answer which was acted upon (deleted) after being flagged. And yes this site welcomes everyone but it’s not because of who he is, but because of the way he behaves (random downvote+ No site policy) action must be taken against him. Please refrain from entering the site/answering if you don’t like Hinduism

Comment: I agree about the random downvoting part .. what we can do here is to report using the contact us form. Write to them what you think is wrong about some users' actions. They have all the tools with them to verify your claims and they can take appropriate actions @Archit

Comment: Okay and in the interim about the weird answers? The basic reason for this meta post?

Comment: That has to be dealt with using flagging. We can get them either deleted or get the banner added to them. But I agree that most of these answers are written with no proper knowledge about Hinduism. Some are absurd answers @Archit

Comment: Banner? And what about all the pending flags?

Comment: The "citation needed" banner in case where no reference is found. Only Mods can handle flags. So, it depends on their mercy :P Even many of my flags are pending which IMO are quite easy to handle. In fact that is why I had asked a Q on whether other site Mods can handle our flags or not. @Archit

Comment: Accha same. How do you put that banner? Something like this?: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/39862/are-varna-and-caste-same-or-different/39863#39863. This was when I just joined the site my very first answer. Updated it later.

Comment: If you find an answer that does not cite sources you have to flag it using the reason "in need of moderator intervention" and then explain in the message box that a banner is needed here as no sources are cited @Archit A mod will then review the flag and add the banner.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118157/discussion-on-question-by-rickross-how-are-these-answers-answering-the-question).